# Should provide default constructor?

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

I have an app that I transferred to the new android studio. When I try and generate a signed apk I get this error:

```
Error:(24) Error: This fragment should provide a default constructor (a public constructor with no arguments) (com.example.mike.beerportfolionewicon.BarcodeFrag) [ValidFragment]
```

The class starts off like this:

```
public class BarcodeFrag extends Fragment implements ReadJSONResult.OnArticleSelectedListener {

    private ListView lv;
    View v;
    SearchView searchView;
    private SearchView mSearchView;
    private MenuItem mSearchMenuItem;
    String id;

    public BarcodeFrag(String scanContent) {
        id = scanContent;


    }
```

I selected an option to ignore inspection but it still will not create an apk...

Tried changing it to this, but same error:

```
public class BarcodeFrag extends Fragment implements ReadJSONResult.OnArticleSelectedListener {

    private ListView lv;
    View v;
    SearchView searchView;
    private SearchView mSearchView;
    private MenuItem mSearchMenuItem;
    String id;

    public BarcodeFrag(){}

    public BarcodeFrag(String scanContent) {
        id = scanContent;


    }
```

Actually its a different error:

```
Error:(35) Error: Avoid non-default constructors in fragments: use a default constructor plus Fragment#setArguments(Bundle) instead [ValidFragment]
```

The entire code now looks like this:

```
public class BarcodeFrag extends Fragment implements ReadJSONResult.OnArticleSelectedListener {

    private ListView lv;
    View v;
    SearchView searchView;
    private SearchView mSearchView;
    private MenuItem mSearchMenuItem;
    String id;

    public BarcodeFrag(){}

    public BarcodeFrag(String scanContent) {
        id = scanContent;


    }




    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //set layout here
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_search, container, false);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        getActivity().setTitle("Search");


        //get user information
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        String userName = prefs.getString("userName", null);
        String userID = prefs.getString("userID", null);


        //run code with barcode content
        String url = "http://api.brewerydb.com/v2/search/upc?code="+ id +"&key=xxx&format=json&withBreweries=y";

        //run async task
        ReadJSONResult task = new ReadJSONResult(getActivity());
        task.setOnArticleSelectedListener(this);
        task.execute(url);




        return v;


    }

    @Override
    public void onArticleSelected(String b, String brewery){

        //code to execute on click
        Fragment Fragment_one;
        FragmentManager man= getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction tran = man.beginTransaction();

        Fragment_one = new BeerTabs();
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putString("beerID",b);
        editor.putString("breweryID",brewery);
        editor.commit();


        tran.replace(R.id.main, Fragment_one);//tran.
        tran.addToBackStack(null);
        tran.commit();





    }
}
```

Comment: Just add `public BarcodeFrag(){}`

Comment: Did you try to add a default constructor?

Comment: where in the code, I added it after the public BarcodeFrag (String scanContent){...}

And it did not work

Comment: Are you still getting the same error?

Comment: added what i tried doing to my original post and it did not help

Comment: actually its a different error, posted above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fragment must have an empty constructor due to life cycle reasons.
consider replacing the one you got with en empty one and pass `String scanContent` via `Bundle`. in that way you can assure that the fragment always get your `scanContent` even if the fragment recreated itself.

```
Fragment fragment = new Fragment() {
        @Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
            super.onAttach(activity);
            if(getArguments() != null) {
                String scanContent = getArguments().getString("scanContent");
            }
        }
    };

Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("scanContent", scanContent);
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

**Edit:**

From your `Activity`:

```
BarcodeFrag fragment = new BarcodeFrag();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("scanContent", scanContent);
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

On your `Fragment`, replace

```
 public BarcodeFrag(String scanContent) {
    id = scanContent;
 }
```

with

```
public BarcodeFrag() {
}
```

and get the `id` from `onCreateView(...)` like so:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if(id == null && getArguments() != null) {
        String scanContent = getArguments().getString("scanContent");
        this.id = scanContent;
    }
    .
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Comment: confused on how to change my code, I posted the entire class now above.

Comment: You cannot have a constructor with arguments.  Remove this `public BarcodeFrag(String scanContent) {
        id = scanContent;


    }`

Comment: where does that if statement go?

Comment: @Mike please be more specific

Comment: where does this code go after I add public BarCodeFrag(){}:

if(getArguments() != null) {
    String scanContent = getArguments().getString("scanContent");
    this.id = scanContent;
}

Comment: I tred this:

public BarcodeFrag() {

        if(getArguments() != null) {
            String scanContent = getArguments().getString("scanContent");
            this.id = scanContent;
        }
    }

Comment: dont call getArgument() from the constructor because it called before you set the arguments to the fragment. call getArguments() from onCreateView(). I've updated my answer with this solution

Comment: Fyi you can't have a parameterized constructor because in case the fragment gets killed Android needs to know how to rebuild it.

Answer (score 2):

Remove

```
public BarcodeFrag(String scanContent) {
    id = scanContent;
}
```

A `Fragment` in Android should never have a non-empty constructor. Instead, you can create a `static` initiator factory method inside your `Fragment` as follows:

```
public static final String SCAN_CONTENT = "param";
private String scanContent;

public static final BarcodeFrag instanceOf(String scanContent) {
    BarcodeFrag fragment = new BarcodeFrag();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(SCAN_CONTENT, scanContent);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
```

Now, to create a new instance of `BarcodeFrag` from any other class,

`Fragment f = BarcodeFrag.instanceOf(scanContent)`

and to access the value `scanContent` within `BarcodeFrag`,

`scanContent = getArguments().getString(SCAN_CONTENT);`

The parameters passed can be of any type, i.e. `int`, `float`, `String` etc.

Try this. This should work;

Comment: the 'this' cannot be referenced from a static content

Comment: sorry my bad ... hang on

Comment: and the instance of part can not be referenced from a static content

Comment: In the past I've created `instanceOf()` methods for `Fragment`s when I needed to pass arguments ... I'll post the correct answer in a moment ... just let me recall the solution :)

Comment: Hey I've posted the correct answer now ... try it out and let me know if it works for you!

Answer (score 0):

If no constructor is defined then Default constructor is automatically created by Compiler.

If any **constructor with argument** is defined.In case if you call default constructor then it will give compile time error.

```
public class P2 {

    public P2(int a) {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        P2 p = new P2(10);
        P2 p1 = new P2(); //compile time error      
    }
}
```

For remove compile time error, **add default constructor too**.

```
public class P2 {

    public P2() { //After adding this constructor, compile time error is removed

    }
    public P2(int a) {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        P2 p = new P2(10);
        P2 p1 = new P2();       
    }
}
```